# Putty: Getting Server refused our key Error

Tags: ssh, putty

I created key pair using `puttygen.exe` (client is windows 8). On server (Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS), I have put my public key in `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`. The public key is this:

```
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABJQAAAQEAopfM6RHOgnuc4Aftn3t4k5UIAT3StCAbn/vg/IMbphbXadshC+79sIlRq3P4zGzMjFTP4hKnzu6ehLV5lmj/qorq3SKT+bPO5Qrac3VbIlrGvuBFDDjP82I2Hwg3HzlsFTstqk++KToapaTYZ7jENEYyPl2wnzITJnt//+4U1o6juoXTKgdNE02hHnRZyHOV/bnkZyJJCEwJv5U0eXSThQnhmXtUxGT8U0HQNFiXfqIIVllhWiCnyrhhIaKz/CIJNAd2VmzyJzQtJtTQX8aWSNVrZju6Sv2/RncTNvsACdNgjjh/FH8PQXaep00jlJ3MOdsC8vz6VSPFbh6iKy1oLQ== rsa-key-20131231
```

So it's correct (one line, no comments, starts with ssh-rsa, etc.)

`.ssh` dir permission level is 700, authorized_keys file permission is 600. Both directory and file owned by the actual user that I try to log in.

When I try connecting I'm getting `'server refused our key'` and server asks for password. That's all. Nothing is logged to `/var/log/auth.log` when attempting to log in with the key.

I've looked everywhere and all articles and tips mention setting chmod 600 and 700 for the file/directory and formatting the key correctly. I've done all this still getting 'refused our key' error and I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Did you tell Putty to use the same key? are you logging in with the same user? is this a default SSH installation, or did you modify sshd_config?

Comment: Puttygen generates 3 keys: private, public and it's own version of private key with .ppk extension. I'm of course using .ppk with putty.exe and pasted public key into .ssh/authorized_keys on server.

It's default SSH installation/configuration, I have not modified sshd_config.

Comment: BTW, I had to create .ssh directory and auhtorized_keys, because it's fresh Ubuntu installation and it wasn't there. Maybe this has something to do with the issue?

Comment: Yes, I'm loging in with the same user (the one where ~/.ssh/authorized_keys is)

Comment: Make sure sshd_config is configured to use public keys, it might not be

Comment: Also, are you trying to access as root? by default Root login is not allowed

Comment: From what I see sshd_config is configured to use puclic keys by default:

RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes

This is sshd_config on a fresh Ubuntu server installation.

I'm trying to log in using my username (pawel), and I have my key in /home/pawel/.ssh/authorized_keys

Comment: Do you see anything in /var/log/auth.log? increase SSH's logs' LogLevel to `DEBUG` and see if you can see any issues logged, if it still doesn't show you accessing you are looking in the wrong log file

Comment: Thanks for help. See my ansewer below. +1 to you mate.

Comment: This workaround helped for Putty client: https://askubuntu.com/a/1409528/142864

Answer (score 68, accepted):

OK, there was a small typo in my key. Apparently when pasting to file the first letter was cut off and it started with sh-rsa instead of ssh-rsa.

nrathathaus - your answer was very helpful, thanks a lot, this answer is credited to you :) I did like you said and set this in sshd_conf:

```
LogLevel DEBUG3
```

By looking at the logs I realized that sshd reads the key correctly but rejects it because of the incorrect identifier.

Comment: Which logs did you check and where are they? What is the identifier, you are talking about?

Comment: @user1046647 `LogLevel` is defined in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`. The default log is `/var/log/auth.log` unless defined otherwise in `sshd_config`.

Comment: There must be something with the key generator because I had the same exact problem!

Comment: If you open authorized_key in vim and immediately try to paste the first 's' from the 'ssh_rsa" is treated as vim command after which vim will switch to the insert mode and the remaining text is being pasted. If you enter the insert mode before pasting (e.g. using `i`) the leading 's' won't be cut.

Comment: ! `sudo service ssh restart` for the changes to take effect. Otherwise there was nothing in my auth log-file.

Comment: I enabled LogLevel and restarted ssh service but couldn't find auth.log file in /var/log folder. (I am using CentOs 6.9 and OpenSSH_5.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips) I have another user except root and that is working fine. Only root is getting above error. Other folder and file permissions are correct.

Comment: Same problem. This usually happens if you paste your key into vim without being in insert mode first.

Answer (score 38):

Adding a few thoughts as other answers helped, but were not exact fit.

First of all, as mentioned in accepted answer, edit

```
/etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

and set log level:

```
LogLevel DEBUG3
```

Then restart `sshd` on the server to have it use the changed log level, e.g.:

```
sudo service ssh restart
```

Then try to authenticate, and when it fails, look for log file:

```
/var/log/secure
```

It will have errors you are looking for.

Comment: `/var/log/` exists, but `secure` does not exist. How do I discover which log is being written to?

Comment: The default is `/var/log/auth.log`, at least in my Ubuntu 14.04.1.

Comment: YES! thank you! turns out my pub key file had an invisible \n at the end

Comment: Linux/Ubuntu is so frustrating. Spent a good 20 minutes trying to figure out why there was no `secure` file before reading @axel comments here.

Comment: I couldn't find any ubuntu log file, I eventually read the logs using "journalctl -t sshd -b0 -r" as mentioned in https://serverfault.com/a/1054725/698635

Answer (score 23):

In my case I had to change the permissions of /home/user from 0755 to 0700 as well.

Comment: this was the cause and solution for me

Comment: and for myself folder 700 and authorized_keys 600 solved the problem

Comment: For me the same, chmod 700 on .ssh folder and chmod 600 on authorized_keys solved the problem

Comment: .ssh folder 700 and authorized keys 600 fixed it for me.

Answer (score 22):

In my case, is a permission problem.

I changed the log level to `DEBUG3`, and in `/var/log/secure` I see this line:

```
Authentication refused: bad ownership or modes for directory
```

Googled and I found this post:

https://www.daveperrett.com/articles/2010/09/14/ssh-authentication-refused/

```
chmod g-w /home/$USER
chmod 700 /home/$USER/.ssh
chmod 600 /home/$USER/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Basically, it tells me to:

- get rid of group `w` permission of your user home dir
- change permission to `700` of the `.ssh` dir
- change permission to `600` of the `authorized_keys` file.

And that works.

**Another thing is that even I enabled root login, I cannot get `root` to work. Better use another user.**

Comment: This answer was under-voted. The overlooked permissions of the home directory may cost you a whole day to troubleshoot.

Comment: Thanks for voting up for me. I just share what I got.

Comment: For anyone coming here trying to understand where the `'bad ownership or modes for directory'` error comes from, I'm posting here because it took me quite a bit of searches to find it myself. This is enforced by the [`StrictModes`](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config#StrictModes) setting in `sshd_config`.  It's not recommended to disable, but it is helpful for troubleshooting.

Answer (score 10):

If you run **Putty in a version before 0.75**, then updating Putty should solve the problem.

Newer version of openSSH (as in Ubuntu 22.04) have deprecated the use of the SHA1 hashing algorithm during the login, but Putty used SHA1 until version 0.74.

If sshd log file on the server shows

```
$ sudo grep 'sshd' /var/log/auth.log
sshd[113232]: userauth_pubkey: key type ssh-rsa not in PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms [preauth]
```

then this in fact is causing the error, and it should be gone after Putty has been updated.

Comment: Thanks, your solution is works.
@not2savvy could explain what this means. Is it the hashing or encryption is not supported anymore?
I couldn't find reference about this.

Comment: @YGautomo As mentioned in the answer, it‘s SHA1 that doesn’t work any more (considered to weak).

Comment: Worked for me as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Running Windows 8.1 I ran into the `server refused our key` problem.

Following the guide: https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_windows_openssh_server
It was easy to make a connection using the Windows login `username` and `password`. However, authenticating with the `username` in combination with a `private key`, the response was `server refused our key`.

Getting it to work with a public key came down to the **permissions on the file:**
`C:\ProgramData\ssh\administrators_authorized_keys`

This is a helpful page: https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/wiki/Troubleshooting-Steps

Stop the two OpenSSH services, then open a `command prompt` with `admin permissions`. Then run:
`C:\OpenSSH-Win32>c:\OpenSSH-Win32\sshd.exe -ddd`

Note: specify the full path to the exe otherwise `sshd` complains.
This creates a one-time use connection listener. The `-ddd` is verbose level 3.

After making a connection, scanning the logs revealed:

```
debug1: trying public key file __PROGRAMDATA__/ssh/administrators_authorized_keys
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/administrators_authorized_keys error:2
debug1: Could not open authorized keys '__PROGRAMDATA__/ssh/administrators_authorized_keys':
        No such file or directory
```

Had to create the file: `C:\ProgramData\ssh\administrators_authorized_keys`
And copy the `public key` text into it, e.g: `ssh-rsa AAAA................MmpfXUCj rsa-key-20190505`
And then save the file. I saved the file as `UTF-8` with the `BOM`. Didn't test `ANSI`.

Then running the one-time command line again, in the logs showed:

```
debug1: trying public key file __PROGRAMDATA__/ssh/administrators_authorized_keys
debug3: Bad permissions. Try removing permissions for user: S-1-5-11 on file C:/ProgramData/ssh/administrators_authorized_keys.
        Authentication refused.
```

`S-1-5-11` is the name given to the `System`.

To fix the `Bad permissions`, right click on the `administrators_authorized_keys` file, goto the `Security Tab` , click the `Advanced` button and remove inherited permissions.
Then delete all `Group or user names:` except for the Windows login username, e.g: `YourMachineName\username`
The permissions for that `username` should be `Read Allow`, `Write Deny` everything else is unchecked. The owner of the file should also be `YourMachineName\username`

This fixed the problem.

Other Useful links:

Download OpenSSH-Win32.zip from: https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/releases

C# example of how to use the WinSCPnet.dll to make a connection to the OpenSSH server: https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library#csharp

Here is the code snippet to make a connection using the `WinSCPnet.dll`:

```
static void WinSCPTest() {
    SessionOptions ops = new SessionOptions {
        Protocol = Protocol.Sftp, 
        PortNumber = 22,
        HostName = "192.168.1.188", 
        UserName = "user123",
        //Password = "Password1",
        SshHostKeyFingerprint = @"ssh-rsa 2048 qu0f........................ddowUUXA="
    };

    ops.SshPrivateKeyPath = @"C:\temp\rsa-key-20190505.ppk";

    using (Session session = new Session()) {
        session.Open(ops);
        MessageBox.Show("success");
    }
}
```

Replace `SshHostKeyFingerprint` and `SshPrivateKeyPath` with your own values.

Edit: added screenshot of administrators_authorized_keys file permissions:
[image]

When `OpenSSH SSH Server` is running as a Service, then only `System` should have permission. However, if running `sshd.exe` from the command prompt, then the current user should be the only one listed (read allow, write deny).

Comment: You have done many things here that helped. First running sshd with debug flag on command line. Windows Service System logs showed very little and was totally useless to debug. Second, the main fact that as an Administrator there is a bug that only looks in the administrators_authorized_keys file and not the expected Users .ssh folder for authorized_keys (everybody's point of grief running sshd on Windows). Finally the 'ssh' folder in ProgramData! I was wondering where it was putting the server certs etc. So only your information here helped me after scratching my head for a day or so. Thanks!

Comment: this answer was the only one which worked for me on a fresh ec2 instance windows 2019 free tier.

Answer (score 4):

The simple solution i found was to move the `authorized_keys` file away from the hidden .ssh directory and put it in the system ssh directory:

```
/etc/ssh/keys/authorized_keys
```

As soon as I did this it worked with no problems.

Answer (score 4):

having same issue in windows server 2008 r2 and explored a lot to solve, finally did that by following:

open C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenSSH\etc\sshd_config with textpad or any other text editor

remove comment from following lines, after removing they should look like following:

```
RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
AuthorizedKeysFile  .ssh/authorized_keys
```

save it and try to login with private key now. 
have fun.

Comment: ssh sometimes is installed w/ the authorizedkeysfile line commented out so it doesn't know where to look for the authorized keys file :-(

Comment: What are the permissions needed for the authorized_keys file? And does it have to be in the user directory or in the directory of OpenSSH?

Comment: It should be on OpenSSH directory or where you installed your OpenSSH. you should be able to find it

Comment: Make sure, you are setting it up using Admin account.

Answer (score 3):

I'm adding this answer to help anyone, like me, who spent hours scouring the internet without success.

YOUR HOME FOLDER MIGHT BE ENCRYPTED.

Or for that matter any folder in which your "authorized_keys" file is nested. Man, that would have saved me a lot of time. To check, go perform

```
ls -A
```

on the directory whose encryption status you would like to determine. If the folder contains a folder named ".encryptfs" the answer is, yes, that folder is encrypted. This will impede your ability to access the "authorized_keys" file containing the public ssh key needed for verification.

To fix this, place the "authorized_key" file in a directory tree that contains no encryption.

Answer (score 3):

After adding key, login as `ec2-user` if you are using an Amazon Linux machine

If its ubuntu machine then use `ubuntu`

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to nrathaus and `/var/log/auth.log` investigation on debug level comes the following.

Another reason is that your home directory may have permissions different than 755.

Comment: Your home directory should be 700, that is the default on CentOS.

Answer (score 2):

In my case it was caused by (`/etc/ssh/sshd_config`):

```
PermitRootLogin no
```

Changed to `yes`, restarted the service and got in normally.

Comment: dangerous answer!

Answer (score 2):

I have solved this problem,puttygen is a third-party software, ssh key which generated by it didn't be used directly, so you must make some changes.
For example, it look like this

```
---- BEGIN SSH2 PUBLIC KEY ----
Comment: "rsa-key-20170502"
AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABJQAAAQEAr4Ffd3LD1pa7KVSBDU+lq0M7vNvLp6TewkP7
*******C4eq1cdJACBPyjqUCoz00r+LqkGA6sIFGooeVuUXTOxbYULuNQ==
---- END SSH2 PUBLIC KEY ----
```

I omit some of the alphabets in the middle, replaced by *, if not, StackOverflow told me that the code format is wrong, do not let me post。

this is my ssh key generated by puttygen, you must change to this

```
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABJQAAAQEAr4Ffd3LD1pa7KVSBDU+lq0M7vNvLp6TewkP7wfvKGWWR7wxA8GEXJsM01FQw5hYWbNF0CDI7nCMXDUEDOzO1xKtNoaidlLA0qGl67bHaF5t+0mE+dZBGqK7jG9L8/KU/b66/tuZnqFqBjLkT+lS8MDo1okJOScuLSilk9oT5ZiqxsD24sdEcUE62S8Qwu7roVEAWU3hHNpnMK+1szlPBCVpbjcQTdiv1MjsOHJXY2PWx6DAIBii+/N+IdGzoFdhq+Yo/RGWdr1Zw/LSwqKDq1SmrpToW9uWVdAxeC4eq1cdJACBPyjqUCoz00r+LqkGA6sIFGooeVuUXTOxbYULuNQ== yourname@hostname
```

In my case, I have deleted some comments, such as

```
---- BEGIN SSH2 PUBLIC KEY ----
Comment: "rsa-key-20170502"
---- END SSH2 PUBLIC KEY ----
```

and add `ssh-rsa` at the beginning,
 add `yourname@hostname` at the last.
 **note**: not delete`==` in the last and you must change "yourname" and "hostname" for you, In my case, is `uaskh@mycomputer`,yourname is that you want to log in your vps .when all these things have  done,you could to upload public-key to uaskh's home`~/.ssh/authorized_keys` by `cat public-key >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys` then `sudo chmod 700 ~/.ssh` `sudo chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys` then you must to modify /etc/ssh/sshd_config, `RSAAuthentication yes` `PubkeyAuthentication yes` `AuthorizedKeysFile .ssh/authorized_keys` my operating system is CentOS 7,This is my first time to anwser question,I will try my efforts to do ,Thank you!

Comment: @Ronak Bhatt, Thank you efforts for me, I tried to make codes clearer, for all this code I used ctrl + K, but StackOverflow told me "your answer appeal contain codes, please use correct format", and I don't why it's different between written and submitted, I cannot submit my answer, which leads me to have to add codes in 'code' line by line. I will learn markdown format, thinks.

Comment: In the current version PuttyGen will show the public key in the correct format for copy&paste. So there is no need anymore to manually convert the putty pub key to the correct format.

Comment: @ErikKalkoken yes, the copy-paste of the public key worked for me. I don't know why save public key is not in the correct format. I saved the public key using save public key button and copied it to server. But the format was not working as mentioned by nuclear in his answer. 
The sad part is I didn't scroll down to this answer before figuring out myself. But thanks for this answer and your comment.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered this problem today and my issue was that when copying the public key from file, new line characters are included as well. You can use ":set list" in vim to see all the hidden new lines and make sure to delete all the new lines except for the last one. Also, my key was missing "ssh-rsa " in the beginning. Make sure you have that as well.

Comment: Similar here: when copying from PuttyGen, I had new lines after "ssh-rsa " and after the key. After removing them, it worked.

Answer (score 2):

The equivilent of an SSH command:

```
ssh -i <path_to_pem_file> ec2-user@calendar.com
```

In Windows, first use PuTTYGen to convert the pem file to a ppk file.

1. Open **PuTTYGen**
2. File/Load the private pem key *(or an OpenSSH key)*
3. In the Open FileDialog, use the drop down to select "All files" (it only shows ppk file formats not pem, *also OpenSSH key files that can be converted like pem files don't have a file extension*)
4. File/Save private key (*.ppk)

The same settings in Putty as the SSH command:

1. Open **Putty**
2. Session/Hostname: calendar.com
3. Connection/Data/Auto-login username: ec2-user
4. Connection/SSH/Auth/PrivateKeyFile Path: the file path to the PPK file

Answer (score 2):

> OpenSSH disable the ssh-rsa signature scheme by default in the next
> release.
>
> In the SSH protocol, the "ssh-rsa" signature scheme uses the SHA-1
> hash algorithm in conjunction with the RSA public key algorithm. It is
> now possible[1](https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-8.7#:%7E:text=openssh%20will%20disable%20the%20ssh-rsa%20signature%20scheme%20by%20default%20in%20the%20next%20release.%20) to perform chosen-prefix attacks against the SHA-1
> algorithm for less than USD$50K.

[Source](https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-8.7#:%7E:text=openssh%20will%20disable%20the%20ssh-rsa%20signature%20scheme%20by%20default%20in%20the%20next%20release.%20)

So, update the key.

Answer (score 2):

This helps to me:

```
# /etc/ssh/sshd_config
PubkeyAuthentication yes
PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes=+ssh-rsa

# temporarily added:
LogLevel DEBUG3
# gentoo
# tail -n 50 /var/log/messages
```

and restart sshd

```
/etc/init.d/sshd restart
```

Comment: Debug3 showed "userauth_pubkey: key type ssh-rsa not in PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms", fixed by adding "PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes=+ssh-rsa". More info https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=270005

Answer (score 1):

For those receiving this error from Windows Server, I received this same error and it was a user account issue. With many organizations, group policy for Administrators may not allow setting up SSH Server and connections. With that type of setup, this must be done from Local Admin account. Might be worth looking into if you have confirmed there are not any typos in the public key.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had to disable SELinux on Centos6.6 to get it working :)

Edit /etc/selinux/config and set the following and then reboot the host.

```
selinux=disabled
```

BTW...forgot to mention that I had to set the LogLevel=DEBUG3 to identify the issue.

Comment: Rather than disabling SELinux you can change the security context on the .ssh folder. chcon -R -t ssh_home_t .ssh

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error on solaris but found in /var/adm/splunk-auth.log the following:

```
sshd: [auth.debug] debug1: PAM conv function returns PAM_SUCCESS
sshd: [auth.notice] Excessive (3) login failures for weblogic: locking account.
sshd: [auth.debug] ldap pam_sm_authenticate(sshd-kbdint weblogic), flags = 1
sshd: [auth.info] Keyboard-interactive (PAM) userauth failed[9] while authenticating: Authentication failed
```

In /etc/shadow the account was locked:

```
weblogic:*LK*UP:16447::::::3
```

Removed the "*LK*" part:

```
weblogic:UP:16447::::::3
```

and I could use ssh with authorized_keys as usual.

Answer (score 1):

I have this issue where sshd only reads from `authorized_keys2`.

Copying or renaming the file fixed the problem for me.

```
cd  ~/.ssh
sudo cat authorized_keys >> authorized_keys2
```

P.S. I'm using Putty from Windows and used PuTTyKeygen for key pair generation.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing similar issue when trying to logon through Mobaxterm. The private key was generated through puttygen. Regenerating the key helped in my case.

Answer (score 1):

As my experience, I suggest you should generate keys from putty, should not generate from linux side. Because the key will be old PEM format. Anyway, just my suggestion. I did as steps below and worked fine with me and with my team.

1. Generate a key pair with PuTTYGen.exe on your local (type: RSA, length: 2048 bits).
2. Save private/public key as "**id_rsa.ppk/id_rsa.pub**" files on your local.
3. Create "authorized_keys" file on your local, then enter the public key in "**id_rsa.pub**" to "**authorized_keys**".
   Remember content has to begin with "**ssh-rsa**" and **one line only**.

[image]

4. Use WinScp (or putty command) to copy "**authorized_keys & id_rsa.pub**" from your local to your linux-user-home "**/home/$USER/.ssh/**".

[image]

5. Run these commands:

   chmod 700 .ssh

   chmod 600 .ssh/authorized_keys

   chown $USER:$USER .ssh -R
6. Test your connect setting by load the private key "**id_rsa.ppk**" in the PuTTY.exe profile, then click open (put your passphrase if have).

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

check your key, this should be a rsa (id_rsa.pub) key today and no longer a dss (id_dsa.pub) key, use puttygen 0.70 and choose RSA on type of key to generate, replace the public key on host ~/.ssh/authorized_keys

Answer (score 1):

Oh my God I spent days trying to fix this. So here is what worked for me. I went back to the root fold like this:
cd /root/
mkdir .ssh
cd .ssh
chmod 700 .ssh
nano -w authorized_keys
service ssh restart
 So I used root to logging via Putty and it worked. so try to do the same with the user you want to use in putty.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of mine it was a wrong user:group attribution. I solved setting the right user and group:

```
sudo chown [user]:[group] -R /home/[user]
```

Answer (score 1):

I was running putty 0.70 and had to upgrade to the newest version. It worked correctly for ubuntu 18, but when running version 22 it threw the above error.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I did the following things to make it work (**Using Windows 10 with PuTTY and Raspberry Pi 4b running Ubuntu Desktop 22.10 x64**):

I'd been at war with this issue for two days and nothing seemed to work until I tried these simple steps.

1. Use latest available version of PuTTY
2. Right click on the public key string in PuTTYgen and pick **"Select All"** before copying it
3. When creating the **".ssh"** directory, **"authorized_keys"** file and running chmod command make sure **not** to use the sudo command
4. Remember also to always edit the **authorized_key** file as the currently logged in user and not with sudo command

Worked like a charm

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a PUTTYgen file with psftp, and I encountered this problem on my Windows Server when we were required to create new keys for a client. The *private_key_name*.ppk file and the open_ssh.txt file must be in the same directory for the connection to work.

Answer (score 0):

In my case home on nfs was 777, needed to be 750. That fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

When using Cpanel you can check if the key is authorized in

SSH Access >> Public keys >> Manage >> Authorize or Deauthorize.

Answer (score 0):

if you get this error in `/var/log/secure`

> error: key_read: key_from_blob AA
>   AAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABJQAAAQEAoo3PFwX04NFG+rKz93l7em1BsUBzjHPMsswD

it means your key is having space, if you generated key through puttgen when you view `.ppk` file, it will look like this:

```
AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABJQAAAQEAoo3PFwX04NFG+rKz93l7em1BsUBzjHPMsswD
al74MLaJyhQD0pE23NS1izahbo1sJGnSJu2VJ//zxidSsba6xa6OvmeiKTwCz0E5
GMefdGVdpdbTlv99qjBl1+Nw1tDnHIC0+v9XmeZERQfCds9Kp1UivfReoYImntBC
gLtNyqRYrSu8csJCt7E1oY8QK6WP1vfYgAQ2taGyS9+g7FHyyf5VY2vH3oWzzbqz
xjsSLAv3zEQSm1LzSw9Pvc8iwasFyUMBOPj31CKQYTXyX8KpJTr0Zb7oqMauBE5L
VwxZhlcJHbj0FsMbF/+GRjvgexymCi3bHmwGQ6FEADNd0RkhdQ==
```

and when you try to paste it you will get an error in reading key, so try to edit key and make it one line and try it

this should look like something

`ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABJQAAAQEAoo3PFwX04NFG+rKz93l7em1BsUBzjHPMsswDal74MLaJyhQD0pE23NS1izahbo1sJGnSJu2VJ//zxidSsba6xa6OvmeiKTwCz0E5GMefdGVdpdbTlv99qjBl1+Nw1tDnHIC0+v9XmeZERQfCds9Kp1UivfReoYImntBCgLtNyqRYrSu8csJCt7E1oY8QK6WP1vfYgAQ2taGyS9+g7FHyyf5VY2vH3oWzzbqzxjsSLAv3zEQSm1LzSw9Pvc8iwasFyUMBOPj31CKQYTXyX8KpJTr0Zb7oqMauBE5LVwxZhlcJHbj0FsMbF/+GRjvgexymCi3bHmwGQ6FEADNd0RkhdQ== username@domainname`

Answer (score 0):

What works for me is that:

- Stopped the ec2 instance
- detach the volume
- attach the volume with the old instance using the same key and was able to SSH
- mount the volume in some temp folder
- checked the file in the directory mount_point/home/ec2-user/.ssh/authorized_keys

  - Ideally, this file needs to have our key information but for me this file was empty
- copied the old instance authorized_keys file to the newly mounted volume
- unmount the device
- reattach to the original ec2 instance
- start it and let it pass the health checks

This time it works for me. But I don't know why it doesn't have my key file information at first when the instance was launched. Check this link too https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/TroubleshootingInstancesConnecting.html#TroubleshootingInstancesConnectingMindTerm

Answer (score 0):

On my case the problem was like this, during the generation of ssh keys I intentionally changed the default directories of the keys. So instead of using the location ~/.ssh/authorized_keys I chose to use `~/home/user/folder1/.ssh/authorized_keys`, for these changes to work I was supposed to make the same changes of about the new location on this file `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`. But until I am realising this I had already tried several solutions suggested by other people here including setting the permission of home folder to `700` and the .ssh directory to `600`.

Answer (score 0):

Steps to fix Root mount (That i followed as i changed permission with ec2-user folder and the authorization key file)
This process will be similar to detach and attach a pen-drive

**Below are some other scenarios you may encounter -**

> 1. You're using an SSH private key but the corresponding public key is not in the authorized_keys file.
> 2. You don't have permissions for your authorized_keys file.
> 3. You don't have permissions for the .ssh folder.
> 4. Your authorized_keys file or .ssh folder isn't named correctly.
> 5. Your authorized_keys file or .ssh folder was deleted.

**Steps to fix them**

- Stop the problematic Ec2 instance
- Detach the root volume (/dev/sda1)
- Create an ec2 instance or use an running one
- Mount the detached volume (/dev/sdvf) to new ec2 instance

**Now after you login to new ec2 run below steps**

- Lsblk command - list all available mounts
- Pick the mount value that you unmount from the problematic instance
- As ec2-user run “sudo mount /dev/mapper/rootvg-home /mnt”
  `sudo mount /dev/mapper/rootvg-home /mnt`
- Then change directory to /mnt
- Make all necessary changes

**Now we have fixed our volume with the issue that we faced. Mostly it could be user permission issue**
- Umount /mnt to unmounts it 
- Now go to the console and point to the volume attached to new instance and detach it 
- After detached, attached it to your new volume as /dev/sda1

**With that said you should be able to login successfully**

Answer (score 0):

I just updated Putty since I could connect with WinSCP. Now it works with Putty as well

Answer (score 0):

Before trying all of the answers one by one, try updating your Putty.
Putty 0.74 had this problem. If you are sure your settings are correct, first try updating Putty to at least 0.77

Answer (score 0):

In my case the refused key problem was due by the different location of `authorized_keys` file.

By default, it is `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`, but you have to check the `AuthorizedKeysFile` parameter in the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` to see wich is the real position.

Answer (score -1):

Another reason could be [UTF-8 BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) in the `authorized_keys` file.

Answer (score -1):

If all of the above do not work, try a **ssh-keygen** on the server side

Chck if it's generating a 3072 bit key, if yes, this may be the reason...

Ensure that the client public key that was copied inside the authorized_key file is a 3072 bit sized key, if not regenerate it and retry.